# iframe - pretend it's mobile mode

Tags: javascript, iframe

I integrate an payment service from the bank through an iframe.

I would like the iframe to alsways be on mobile mode. If I use the mobile mode (chrome) it displays well, on the mobile it displays well also, but on my big screen we need to scroll vertically and horizontally inside the iframe. So I would like to find a way to pretend it's a mobile screen.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Try changing size of iframe element, particularly it's width

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't have the desired behaviour